# Replace Vintage Shimano Trigger Shifter

Tags: shimano, shifter, vintage, cannondale

I have a Cannondale M600 Red White & Blue. 
My 7 speed Shimano integrated trigger shifter will no longer function.

I cannot tell the model[image]

I cannot fix it nor find an identical replacement what other compatible Shimano shifters Can I use?
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the shifter?

Comment: Does it sort-of work if you carefully manipulate the triggers?  Did it gradually get worse or did it suddenly stop working completely?   Can you hear/feel it click?  Was this the result of accident/dropping the bike ?    If you pull the visible inner cable with your hand, does the derailleur visibly move?

Comment: And do you want to replace it or fix it  - IE are you comfortable with hand tools or you just want to ID the thing and pay someone else to fix it ?

Comment: Replace with seperate shifter and brake lever, then you have lots of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking up the [M600 on Bicycle Blue Book](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/15058/), it seems it was outfitted with Shimano STX SE Rapidfire shifters to work the 3x7 drivetrain. A Google search of "Shimano STX SE Rapid fire Shifter" yielded several results, including many videos on fixing a problematic STX shifter and it's rapid fire cousins.  You dont describe the specific problem with yours but often with these types of shifters, the pawls become stuck with old dried grease and dirt and thus the shifting is unreliable or non-existent.  Removing the cover and dousing the innards with WD-40 or similar degreaser while working the levers will clean the mechanism, freeing up the pawls, restoring their motion, and the shifter begins to function anew.  Follow up the cleaning with application of a better lubricating spray grease and you may have a reconditioned shifter to use. Details can be found in several videos offered by search engine. [Here's one such video](https://www.bikeride.com/rapid-fire-shifters/).

Should you want or need replacement STI's, Shimano's current and readily available  model, ST-EF500, is a 3x7  set-up and would be a drop in replacement.  However if it's original, stock equipment you must have, the same search as above contained hits of the STX for sale, even a couple NOS (New Old Stock).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Before posting this I had watched multiple videos on repairing it. WD40 doesn’t help. The return spring for the shifter appears to be Past its end of life date. If i manually move it it will work but under no other condition will it spring back so that you can hear the click.. in answer to the other questions I am looking to simply replace it. This is a great forum and thank you for volunteering your advice